# React Native ListView Recycling

Tags: ios, react-native

I am playing around with React Native and was attempting to create a long list of cards use a ListView component that a user could scroll through (very similar to Facebooks current app). What I'm noticing is that when I create a large number of cards, the memory foot print of the application continues to grow as a scroll through them. It does not grow unless I'm scrolling.

How I am interpreting this is that the ListView is only rendering views just before they become visible which is exactly what it should be doing. What I don't see, however, is it freeing views once they are invisible from being scrolled off screen. Is there some attribute that needs to be set to enable this? How can I manage the memory for long lists in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone is on the right path already.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/499#issuecomment-128836161

Answer (score 1):

ListView holds onto all of its row components because they may be stateful (that is, have `this.state`) but you can tell it to free the underlying native views with the `removeClippedSubviews` prop:

> This is a special performance property exposed by RCTView and is useful for scrolling content when there are many subviews, most of which are offscreen. For this property to be effective, it must be applied to a view that contains many subviews that extend outside its bound. The subviews must also have overflow: hidden, as should the containing view (or one of its superviews).

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#removeclippedsubviews.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Looking at the implementatioin of ListView it looks like this removeClippedSubviews method is just a stub in the objective-c code. Am I missing something here? Thanks